# How to exaust a machine's resources with RethinkDB?

Tags: node.js, performance, resources, database-performance, rethinkdb

I'm asking this question because I would like to understand how I can run RethinkDB better, which means what kind of hardware should it be running on, what kind of filesystem it should  be running on and other system configurations to maximize it's throughput.

I'm trying to fill a table as fast as I can with documents that are `{"n": <counter>, "rand": <Math.random()>}`. I read somewhere that this is faster with batches of 200 documents, so that's what I'm inserting. I am also using soft durability. I started one nodejs process of this and I can insert on average 10k documents per second, pretty good.

But while this is happening, rethinkdb is using about 70% of one core (I have 8 virtual cores, it's an i7-4770) and the nodejs process is using 5%. So it seems that CPU is not the bottleneck.

As soon as I start another nodejs process doing the same thing, the inserts per second on both processes drop to about 4k-5k. Again, the CPU load keeps the same.

I fired `iotop` and I do see a lot of action there, but not what I expected. I configured two SSDs in a RAID0, and a quick `dd` test says I can write and read at about 800MBps. That's far above what the actual read and actual write speed iotop reports (average read ~14MBps average write ~50MBps).

So how can I exaust my machine's resources ? What does rethinkdb need to run faster ? Why doesn't it spend more resources and have a higher throughput ?

More information on what it's running on: It's an [EX40SSD from Hetzner](http://www.hetzner.de/en/hosting/produkte_rootserver/ex40ssd), two SSDs in a software RAID0, ext4 filesystem (tomorrow I'll try to mount it with `noatime` to see if it's better). The rethinkdb configuration is everything by default, the inserts are done to a table that has only one shard and one replica. Please feel free to ask anything else relevant I might have forgotten to mention.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the bottleneck here is the disk system, but not its throughput. What's more likely is that writes are happening in chunks that are too small to be efficient, or that there are delays due to latency between individual writes.
It's also possible that the latency between individual write queries coming from the client and their processing on the server slows the system down.

Here are a few things I recommend trying:

- Increase the batch size further. Your documents are very small. Therefore I think you might get a significantly higher throughput with batches of 1,000-10,000 documents. This might work especially well in combination with the next point.
- Run multiple concurrent clients. You mentioned that you have run 2 clients concurrently, but this might not be enough. I recommend running 16-32 if possible.
- Check the cache size RethinkDB is using. By default, RethinkDB picks the cache size as a fraction of the available memory, but that is not always reliable. I recommend passing a `--cache-size <MB>` parameter to RethinkDB (or adding the `cache-size=<MB>` parameter to the configuration file, if you're using one). I can see that your server has 32 GB of RAM. I recommend using in the range of 20000 MB (or even more) as the cache size. A larger cache reduces the number of reads, but up to a certain limit also increases the amount of unsaved data that RethinkDB can accumulate in RAM to make disk writes more efficient.
- Experiment with the `--io-threads <THREADS>` parameter. The default is 64, but you can try increasing it to e.g. 128 and see if it has any effect.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I did as you suggested and tried having 20 clients, batches of 1000 documents, 20000MB of cache size and 128 io threads but the throuput fell to 1200 inserts per second. Trying out 1 client with the same settings didn't change things much, one client and batches of 200 made the the inserts per second drop to 800. 10 clients inserting batches of 200 documents brought it back to 1200 per second. This is good, I'm getting a sense of things.

Comment: However the CPU load is even lower this time, with only 30%-40%

Comment: Here's another thing to try: we recently found that on some systems you can get significantly better disk throughput by using buffered I/O. To enable that, start the server with `--no-direct-io`.

Comment: Yep I'be been following that github issue, will try that as soon as possible, thanks!

Comment: It actually got better! On the same table (which has > 25M documents with a secondary index) with direct-io I'm getting at most 2K inserts per second, with no-direct-io I'm getting an average of 10k inserts per second!

Comment: Also the average CPU usage by the rethinkdb process is now 200%, much better than 80% from before... iotop says the actual disk write is also about 100M/s, up from 50 :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

What I suspect is going on here is lock contention on the actual btrees. When you're inserting a large batch of documents, the system grabs various parts of the btree in parallel to update it with the new documents. This is a set of read-write locks -- other parts of the system can still read, but if you insert another large batch in parallel, there is a high probability that it will touch similar parts of the btree, and therefore has to wait for the system to start unlocking as it inserts parts of the first batch. (This isn't specific to RethinkDB, but a problem in databases in general) This is likely why you're not hitting 100% CPU/disk throughput.

There are a few things you can try, but note that there are subtleties to various approaches. Benchmarking in general is *hard*.

- You can try to shard the table into 32 shards and retry your benchmark. You don't actually have to create a cluster, you can shard into 32 shards on a single machine. This will result in multiple btrees, so you'll minimize contention and will be able to use more system resources. Note that while this will likely increase the throughput, increasing the number of shards also slightly increases the latency, so you might need to significantly increase parallelism before you start seeing throughput increases.
- You can try *not* to batch writes and instead write one document at a time (which generally approximates real-world use cases a little better). Then, start hundreds of parallel clients instead of just one or two, and have all them write one document at a time in parallel. Note that you need to make sure the clients themselves aren't a bottleneck in this situation.
- You can try to rerun your benchmark and also spin up clients that read from the database in parallel with the writes. In RethinkDB reads can usually go through even when you're writing to a particular document, so this will give you the opportunity to up CPU usage and bypass contention.
- Pay attention to the IDs of the documents. If the database is large enough (say, millions of documents), and the IDs you're inserting are random, you're much less likely to touch the same parts of the btree so contention becomes less of an issue.
- You can combine various approaches (sharding, reading + writing, various numbers of concurrent clients) to start getting a sense for how the database behaves in various scenarios.
- Note that there might be things going on that you wouldn't normally be aware of. For example, RethinkDB has a log-structured storage engine that does live compaction on disk, and this might use up some IO (and CPU) cycles that you'd be surprised by if you didn't know about live compaction. There are dozens of other components like this that might compound to surprising behavior, as these systems are typically very complex under the hood.

Hope this helps -- would love to hear about your progress on the benchmarks. We do a lot of them internally, and it's an art and a science to discover the boundaries of the system's performance on different use cases.

Comment: If you increase the number of shards without adding more servers, be aware though that certain read operations will lose some efficiency. Especially secondary index operations will become significantly slower.

Comment: Quite interesting, at 32 shards and 80 clients doing each 100 inserts in parallel, the inserts per second peak at 2100 but float around 1500 with minimums below 1000. The CPU usage is around 90%, a bit higher than before. I tried this both with the defaults and 128 io threads and 20GB of cache size, the defaults perform with those numbers, cranking up io threads and cache size yields about 50% of that throughput. Doing queries like sum and avg are the only way I can get ~780% of CPU usage which I was expecting from 8 cores.